# How to fix NodeJS underutilizing CPU Cores?

Tags: node.js, performance, go, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

According to this page [Go vs Node.js](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=go&lang2=node), Node.js is not showing to be taking full advantage of CPU cores when running cpu-intensive code.

If I use virtualization and simply add more Node.js instances, will I achieve the same performance as Go? I suppose there still will be overheads and one won't be able to achieve the same performance.

Comment: You can use cluster module but it won't help you improve the request latency. Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple processes will do. For 4 cpus/threads you need 4 Node.js processes to make use of them. That requires a workload that can be split between processes though.

Node.js provides the [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to distribute socket connections between multiple worker processes which may help in some workloads, but I doubt this would help any of the benchmark workloads.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is indeed a single threaded process. However, you can make use of [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to spawn multiple workers on multiple cores.

If you are not using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) for spawning the app, please consider using it. PM2 makes spawning workers on multiple cores super easy.

> pm2 start app.js -i max

This command will spawn workers on each available core.

Also, note that if you are using session/sockets then you might face some problems because of clustering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Cluster module of nodejs in order to take full advantage of CPU cores when running cpu-intensive code.